# distinguish between two elements in html code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to understand how to distinguish between two buttons in my document, I want it to behave so that in addition to hiding the paragraphs, it also hides just the *"Click Me!"* button when clicking *"Hide*".  Where am I going wrong?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){
                $("p").hide(1000);
                $("button name='me'").hide(1000);
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button name="me" type="button" 
                onclick="alert('Hello world!')">Click Me!</button>

        <button>Hide</button>
        <p>This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
        <p>This is another small paragraph.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to hide your button "click me", your selector css need to be "button[name='me']".

If you add a space, you select the child of button.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").hide(1000);
        $("button[name='me']").hide(1000);
    });
});
```